# Group by Week and Count Column Values in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

Looking to do a simple-ish SQL query in rails (using Active Record) and I'm running into some trouble.

I want to return a JSON response so the client can consume the following data structure:

```
{"2014-12-01-2014-12-07": {
        "foo": 100,
        "bar": 50,
        "baz": 20,
        "blah": 10,
    },
    "2014-12-08-2014-12-14": {
        "foo": 40,
        "bar": 550,
        "baz": 210,
        "blah": 10,

    }
}
```

Where `foo`, `bar`, `baz`, `blah` etc. are possible values available in an array on the `Foo` model (from Foo::PossibleStates). I want to return summed counts of each type per week. I know roughly how I'd go about this in Mongo (the world I'm more familiar with), but am running into trouble with the nuances in SQL and Rails/Active Record. Any direction would be greatly appreciated! Here's what I've tried so far:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def index
    start_date = params[:start_date]
    end_date = params[:end_date]
    @jsonFooData = Foo.group('created_at').group("workflow_state").sum('workflow_state')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not an easy task.

If you are using postgres, it could be achieved by one sql and a loop:

```
# models/foo.rb

# call this Foo.count_by_week in your controller
def self.count_by_week
  raw_result = group_by_week_and_state.count

  # {['2014-12-01-2014-12-07', 'foo'] => 100, ['2014-12-01-2014-12-07', 'bar'] => 100, '...' => '...'}

  raw_result.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), result|
     result[k[0]] ||= {}
     result[k[0]][k[1]] = v
  end
end

def self.group_by_week_and_state
  group("#{weekday_query(0)} || \'-\' || #{weekday_query(6)}").group('workflow_state')
end

# build sql part for day offset of week (0 => mon, 6 => sun)
def self.weekday_query(offset)
  "to_char(cast(date_trunc(\'week\', created_at) as date) + #{offset}, \'YYYY-MM-DD\')"
end
```

Comment: I was hoping to accomplish this in a way that would work w/o the db having to be postgres; what would I do if I was using something more minimal, like SQLite?

Comment: The main part I'm having trouble with is getting the results grouped by week; when I run `Foo .select(:id, :workflow_state, :created_at).where(created_at: start_date..end_date) .group_by{ |e| e.created_at.beginning_of_week(:sunday) }` I get an array that's unwieldy to work with.

Comment: For sqlite, change your weekday_query to `"date(created_at, \'weekday #{offset}\', \'-7 days\')"`

Comment: One note for your code above: I think `group_by` is a lot slower than `group` since it uses an extra ruby loop.

Comment: Awesome — thanks! I'll try this out. Coming to rails from the JS world, so working with these hashes/sql queries is a little new

Comment: Ah wait, I think there is a bug in sqlite's `date` function that `weekday 0` is after `weekday 6` actually, don't know why. You could work around by adding a check: `date(created_at, \'weekday #{offset}\'#{", \'-7 days\'" if offset < 4})`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99360/discussion-between-markthethomas-and-hoang-phan).

Answer (score 0):

```
results = Hash.new 0
counts = Hash.new 0 

# Get the results 'foos' with all the foo records grouped by beginning of the week. I'm using 'Monday' here but can be changed to any other weekday.
foos = Foo.all.group_by{|f| f.created_at.beginning_of_week(:monday)}

# loop through each grouped item
foos.collect do |foo| 
  # collect the workflow states and loop through them and count the unique workflow states.
  foo[1].collect{|f| f.workflow_state}.each do |ws| 
    counts[ws] += 1
  end
  # assign the workflow states counts to the beginning of the week
  results[foo[0]] = counts
  # reset the counter to new hash
  counts = Hash.new 0
end

# output the results
puts results
```